# Using output from c# as input to MATLAB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, matlab, opencv, redirect

I'm a little inexperienced with Visual Studio but I'd like to gain some insight into my problem. I have created a class in C# that contains different parameters. I would like to know how to import/redirect the class and values into MATLAB (R2012b) as input to a function I've created in MATLAB.

More specifically, I have a MATLAB function that takes as input 4-2D points: (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) (x4, y4) and performs some calculation to map these into 3D coordinates -- which can be done when the input 2D points are hard coded, but these 2D points are determined using my c# program (coming from an array of points[]).

I need a way to connect the two to perform these calculations.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

process a reads from stdin, process b writes to stdout

just connect them with a pipe

whatevershell> a | b

Comment: stdin and stdout, C# not C++!

Comment: Console.WriteLine, in c#. bear with me for not knowing how matlab reads console input, though

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way but this requires you to place the csv file in some common place like `MyDocuments` accessible by both c# and matlab programs:

1. Write the 4 2D input values in a csv file using c#
2. Read these values in Matlab, [example here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)